# how to send input from one script to another using bash script

Tags: shell-script

I want to send input from one script to another through shell scripts

when  I stop this script it display the message do u want to continue

```
$MAIN_SCRIPT_PATH/first.sh stop
```

I am stopping the script using another script.I need to send yes to this script `first.sh`. How I will do this?

when stopping the first.sh it ask for user input. do you want to continue? I should send yes....

Comment: If it is just a small query, how about defining a [bash function](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html)?

Comment: expect and send in shell script might work.

Comment: echo yes | $MAIN_SCRIPT_PATH/first.sh stop...whether this will work?

Comment: If your first.sh script is running and later you decide to pipe input to it, your question could be a possible duplicate from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374255/how-to-write-data-to-existing-processs-stdin-from-external-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374255/how-to-write-data-to-existing-processs-stdin-from-external-process) If you only need to pipe one time data to the first.sh script, perhaps this answers your question: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/32643326/2019601](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32643326/2019601)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass commands to a script which is waiting for an input on a Linux machine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308194/pass-commands-to-a-script-which-is-waiting-for-an-input-on-a-linux-machine)

Answer (score 1):

You could try writing to stdin of the script and see if that works.  For example,

```
echo yes | $MAIN_SCRIPT_PATH/first.sh stop
```

Otherwise, there are programs like `expect` which allow you to wait for certain prompts before emulating user input.

Also, that's a poorly written script if it is asking for confirmation to stop without giving any additional options.  See if `first.sh --help` displays any additional info around skipping the user input.  There's typically a `-y` / `-q` / `-s` option to scripts which silence user input.

Answer (score 0):

On linux, the coreutils package ships even the `yes` command. So you would run:

```
yes | $MAIN_SCRIPT_PATH/first.sh stop
```